# How to substring a string by specifying number of bytes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to generate ts_vectors for certain fields which are pretty large ( they are larger that the maximum ts_vector limitation ). So I was wondering how could I strip the text to specific byte size ( max 1048575 bytes ).

I have tried using **substring** but it only slices a specific number of characters and most of the time it is smaller than the byte size.

Comment: Please add the SQL code you have tried.

Comment: **SUBSTRING(de.external_description,0,1048570) as external_description**

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what is actually happening, can you post the complete sql,and some sample data, together with wanted output?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a substring with the first 250000 characters of the string, then truncate everything from the last space on (to avoid partial words) and use that.

This is a simple way to be on the safe side, since you'll never encounter UTF-8 characters that exceed 4 bytes. Also (but this is not a technical argument), if relevant key words of a text don't occur in the first 250000 characters, they probably won't occur at all.